# Вывести текст при нажатие ajax

Tags: ajax

Встал в ступор от простой задачи, как сделать так чтобы при нажатие на div сразу отображалось соответствующая информация? и нужна ли переменная data в этом случае?

```
<div id="Mram" class="stone">Мрамор</div>
<div id="Gran" class="stone">Гранит</div>
<div id="MramMoz" class="stone">Мраморная мозайка</div>
<div id="DragKam" class="stone">Полудрагоценные камни</div>
<div id="Omiks" class="stone">Оникс</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9" id="kamen"></div>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#Mram").on("click", function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Mram.html",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: ,
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#kamen").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Какая именно информация должна отображаться и откуда она там возьмётся? Будьте конкретнее.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov в файле Mram.html вот такой. <h2>Мрамор</h2>
<p class="lead">Во все времена изделия из мрамора являлись символом изысканного вкуса их владельца. Формирование мрамора происходит под давлением слоев и воздействием высочайших температур, доходящих до 1000°С, мраморные кристаллы приобретают различные формы и размеры.</p>

Comment: Отобразится она должна в id="kamen" в этом диве. То есть при нажатие на id="Mram", должна информация отобразится в диве с  id="kamen"

Comment: Просто у меня стал вопрос что писать в data нужно в данном случае

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 $("#Mram").on("click", function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "://home/nonick/text.html?callback",
            type: "POST",
            data: {},
            success: function(data){
                $("#kamen").html(data);
             }
         });             
    });
```

в данном примере, data можно оставить пустым

Answer (score 1):

Если код в HTML файле статичен и он располагается на одном и том же домене, то вот так:

```
$.get( "Mram.html", function( data ) {
$( "#kamen" ).html( data ); }
```

Comment: +1 никакого POST-а здесь не надо

Answer (score 0):

В `data` - и это не переменная, кстати, а свойство объекта - вы передаете какие-то данные точно так же, как передавали бы их, просто отправляя POST запрос. Например, форму. Если в данном конкретном примере то, что отдаст сервер на ваш вопрос зависит от каких-либо входных данных, то ответ - да, нужно. Если сервер в любом случае отдаст один и тот же ответ, то и в `data` ничего передавать нет смысла.

В общем случае `data` нужна, например, при регистрации пользователя, когда вы серверу передаете введенный пользователем логин, пароль, возможно еще какие-то данные. В данном случае, судя из поставленного вопроса, он вам не нужен.

И да, если вы на сервер все-таки ничего не передаете, то [лучше передать пустой объект](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject) `{}`.